# Electron forge bundling static assets in build

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-forge

I'm using electron-forge to build an electron app, I am using the webpack template (https://www.electronforge.io/templates/webpack-template). In my application I needed to include static assets (javascript, css and images)

In order to do that I included the `copy-webpack-plugin` in the render.config.js file, this works when testing the application `electron-forge start` however when trying to compile the application `electron-forge build` the assets are not included in the build.

```js
module.exports = {
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([
      { from: './src/images', to: 'images' },
      { from: './src/js', to: 'js' },
      { from: './src/css', to: 'css' },
      { from: './src/webfont', to: 'webfont' }
    ])
  ]
}
```

I expect the css and other assets to be bundled in my application in the same way they are bundled when I test the application.

Comment: No reply on this yet?

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the CopyPlugin configuration in the webpack.plugins.js file instead of render.config.js
2. Your configuration seems incorrect as it miss the [patterns](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#patterns) option.
3. You must provide the full path for CopyPlugin.

Sample :

```
module.exports = [
  new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: [
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/localization/locales'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.webpack/locales')
      }
    ]
  })
]
```

Comment: The `patterns` option is added after [v5](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin/tree/v5), so it's a valid format.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had the same problem using [electron-forge + webpack + typescript](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template), and with [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy some resource files.

**webpack.main.config.js**

```js
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: require('./webpack.rules')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([
      { from: 'resources/credentials.json', to: 'resources/credentials.json'}
    ]),
  ]
}
```

In one of my source files, I tried to read from the file.

```js
const credentialsFile = fs.readFileSync('resources/credentials.json'));
const credentials = JSON.parse(credentialsFile.toString());
```

This worked when running with `electron-forge start`, but when the binary is built with `electron-forge package`, I get the following exception:-

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'resources/credentials.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
...
```

Turns out I just had to add the `__dirname` when building the path.

```
const credentialsFile = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'resources', 'credentials.json'));
```